# Oracle MERGE statement error (ORA-30926)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I inherited an Oracle script running on Oracle 11g that contains the following MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO MainTable PR
     USING IncrementalTable PRA
       ON (PR.contract = PRA.contract
       and PRA.memberType = 'Parent' )
     WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE SET PR.address1 = PRA.address1,
                  PR.city = PRA.city,
                  PR.state = PRA.sate,
                  PR.zipCode = PRA.zipCode,
                  PR.countryCode = PRA.countryCode
WHERE address1 IS NULL
  AND PR.memberType <> 'Parent'
;
```

As far as I can see, this is simply updating the child's address in MainTable from the parent's address in IncrementalTable. Unfortunately, when I run the statement, it throws the following error:

ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

So, it looks like it can't find a distinct match in IncrementalTable with which to update. Querying the data, that appears to be the case:

```
select contract,
       memberType,
       count(*)
  from IncrementalTable
 group by contract,
       memberType
having count(*) > 1
;

CONTRACT               MEMBERTYPE   COUNT(*)
---------------------- ---------- ----------
1119839490             PARENT              2
7271122516             PARENT              2
1004798721             PARENT              2
```

Looking at the details of one of those contracts:

```
select *
  from IncrementalTable
 where contract = '1119839490'
   and memberType = 'Parent'
;


CONTRACT               MEMBERTYPE ADDRESS1          CITY                           STATE ZIPCODE   COUNTRYCODE
---------------------- ---------- ----------------  ------------------------------ ----- -------   -----------
1165439488             Parent     1234 Dorioth St   Orlando                        FL    32825     USA
1165439488             Parent     1234 Dorioth St   Orlando                        FL    32825     USA
```

So, how can I merge only the DISTINCT match from IncrementalTable?

Thanks in adavnce for your help!

Comment: Try to replace:   `...  USING IncrementalTable PRA ...` with `... USING ( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM IncrementalTable ) PRA ...`

Comment: @kordirko has right, you need to abolish the duplicates on the contract and membertype cols, with in the query using distinct, or delete them in the dataset if it possible, its your choise

Comment: @Thomas, you're exactly right. The underlying problem is the "duplicates" in IncrementalTable. Ultimately, I need to have those cleaned up. Thanks!

Comment: @kordirko, Thanks for your syntax suggestions. The underlying problem is the "duplicates" in IncrementalTable. Ultimately, I need to have those cleaned up. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, the merge statement would REALLY have a problem if addresses  weren't "exact" duplicates:

    `CONTRACT               MEMBERTYPE ADDRESS1          CITY                           STATE ZIPCODE   COUNTRYCODE`
    `---------------------- ---------- ----------------  ------------------------------ ----- -------   -----------`
    `1165439488             Parent     1234 Dorioth St   Orlando                        FL    32825     USA`
    `1165439488             Parent     1 Main St         Dallas                         TX    12345     USA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first (and most obvious) answer is to clean up the data so you don't have duplicates. It seems likely that the sample data you provided is the result of a bug.

As for the `merge` statement, if the data is actually purely duplicated, you can just use `distinct`:

```
MERGE INTO maintable pr
USING      (SELECT DISTINCT contract,
                            membertype,
                            address1,
                            city,
                            state,
                            zipcode,
                            countrycode
            FROM   incrementaltable pra
            WHERE  pra.membertype = 'Parent')
ON         (pr.contract = pra.contract)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET pr.address1 = pra.address1,
              pr.city = pra.city,
              pr.state = pra.sate,
              pr.zipcode = pra.zipcode,
              pr.countrycode = pra.countrycode
      WHERE      address1 IS NULL AND pr.membertype <> 'Parent'
```

Comment: Thanks for your syntax suggestions. The underlying problem is the "duplicates" in IncrementalTable. Ultimately, I need to have those cleaned up. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, the merge statement would REALLY have a problem if addresses  weren't "exact" duplicates:

    `CONTRACT               MEMBERTYPE ADDRESS1          CITY                           STATE ZIPCODE   COUNTRYCODE`
    `---------------------- ---------- ----------------  ------------------------------ ----- -------   -----------`
    `1165439488             Parent     1234 Dorioth St   Orlando                        FL    32825     USA`
    `1165439488             Parent     1 Main St         Dallas                         TX    12345     USA`