# Unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables?

Tags: oracle, merge-statement

When I using merge statement, I got the error.

```
Error code 30926, SQL state 99999: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
```

Here my query:

```
merge into dept_fc_link l 
using 
(select distinct dept_id,f_id,stk_point from temp_dept_fc_link) t 
on (l.dept_id = t.dept_id) 
when matched then 
update set l.stk_point = t.stk_point 
when not matched then 
insert(l.dept_id,l.f_id,l.stk_point) values(t.dept_id,t.f_id,t.stk_point);
```

Can point out my mistake?

Comment: What are the two objects in question?  The names imply that they may be synonyms for remote objects?  Are these completely separate permanent tables?

Comment: those are two seperate tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337271/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636860/oracle-merge-statement-error-ora-30926 and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936612/ora-30926-merge-state and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935340/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables-when-merging and a few more.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of error happend when you have duplicates in the query, in other words query in the using clause returns more than 1 row for the joining condition in on clause. 
I don't know your data, but its a good guess.